# 'stack level too deep (SystemStackError)' when running a locally built gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macos-mojave

I checked out this repo https://github.com/cmedley/terraforming and tried to build it locally.

I ran the following

```
bundle install
rake build
gem install pkg/terraforming.gem
```

Then when I ran terraforming in the shell I got the error message:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/terraforming
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:100:in `=~': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:100:in `parse'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:131:in `block in initialize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:131:in `map!'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:131:in `initialize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:59:in `new'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:59:in `create'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:59:in `initialize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:233:in `new'
     ... 8574 levels...
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/terraforming-0.17.1.pre.local/bin/terraforming:22:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/terraforming-0.17.1.pre.local/bin/terraforming:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/terraforming:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/terraforming:22:in `<main>'
```

I have no ruby experience and I only want to run this utility to fix an one-off issue. I would appreciate  simple step by step instructions to resolve this issue, not a load of links to 'understand' the ruby ecosystem.

Ruby version: `ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]`

Comment: It helps to include the [link to the repo](https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming) you cloned. Assuming that's correct, I cannot reproduce this with Ruby 2.6.3 installed with RVM. I recommend that you [don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/), and instead install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.3`, then retry your `gem install` op.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the link https://github.com/cmedley/terraforming

Comment: Still can't reproduce, not sure why you're using a forked repo that is a revision behind the main repo, but that may also contribute to the problems you're having. Follow the instructions above and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: There is a good reason to use a forked repo. This particular one contains a fix that is not in the master repo yet.